# EC2 Deployment in Multiple AWS Regions

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

My Requirement is to deploy the EC2 in Multiple AWS Regions.

Main.tf

```
data "aws_default_tags" "current" {}

module "multi_ec2" {
    source      =   "./multi"
    tier        =   "t1"
    vpc_name    =   "kdt-vpc"
    subnet_name =   "kdt-private-subnet-0"

}
```

In Main.tf I am calling ./multi by passing the vpc name and subnet name and the tier = t1. We have created same vpc name and subnet name in both ohio and virgina region.

If the tier = t1 it should deply both in virgina and ohio region.
if the tier = t2 it should deploy only in virgina region.

mulit folder/main.tf

If you see the code I am calling the module data and ec2 twice one for virgina and one for ohio.

The only change while calling module is to add providers section for ohio module.

The code is fine but we are repeating the modules twice.

Is there any way write two modules is one loop. based on the tier = t1 the whole loop run loop twice and passing the provider sections of virgina and ohio .

if the tier =t2 the loop run one time by passing provider section only virgina.

```
    providers = {
      aws = "aws.west"
    }
```

```
data "aws_default_tags" "current" {}

## Virgina Region

module "data-virgina" {
    count = (var.tier == var.tier1 || var.tier == var.tier2) ? 1 : 0
    source  =   "../data"
}

module "ec2-virgina" {

    count = (var.tier == var.tier1 || var.tier == var.tier2) ? 1 : 0
    source          =   "../ec2"
    ami             =   "ami-0230bd60aa4824569" 
    name            =   var.name
    instance_type   =   module.data-virgina[0].instance-type
    subnet_id       =   module.data-virgina[0].subnet-id

}


## Ohio Region

module "data-ohio" {
    count = (var.tier == var.tier1) ? 1 : 0
    source  =   "../data"
    providers = {
      aws = "aws.west"
    }
}

output "subnet-ohio" {
  description = "The current bid status of the Spot Instance Request"
  value       = module.data-ohio[0].subnet-id
}


module "ec2-ohio" {
    count = (var.tier == var.tier1) ? 1 : 0
    source          =   "../ec2"
    ami             =   "ami-048e636f368eb7890"
    name            =   var.name
    instance_type   =   module.data-virgina[0].instance-type
    subnet_id       =   module.data-ohio[0].subnet-id

    providers = {
        aws = "aws.west"
    }

}
```

Comment: "Is there any way write two modules is one loop. based on the tier = t1 the whole loop run loop twice and passing the provider sections of virgina and ohio ." No, it's not possible to change the provider in a loop. You are going to have some code duplication when using Terraform with multiple providers (multiple AWS regions).